# Typescript: Generic function that returns another generic function with args of the same type

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create a generic factory function that passes on it's generic type to the args of the functions it generates, such that TS is smart enough to know when to fail if the wrong types are passed in. For example, something like the following:

```
type fooFn<T> = <T>(t: T) => T;

const generator = <T,>(): fooFn<T> => {
  return (t: T): T => {
    console.log(t);
    return t;
  }
}

const foo = generator<number>();
foo(1)  // should compile
foo('test') // should fail
```

Right now, this is returning the following errors:

```
Type '(t: T) => T' is not assignable to type 'fooFn<T>'.
  Types of parameters 't' and 't' are incompatible.
    Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T'. Two different types with this name exist, but they are unrelated.
      'T' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'T'.
'T' is declared but its value is never read.
```

What is the right way to implement this?

Playground link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAZg9nAYgOwDwBUB8UC8UOYAUwAXFOgJS7boDcAUPQMZzIDOwUA5hMhAE4BDYHH6586ADREKZeEjRZqUAN70oUfhGABXfsijEylY8rUaNLdnAA2EAHQ24XYhQYXN2vQeDuoAX3pA5lYOWARxHj4hEX5UZB0AWwAjARkGeUIARgp6TIByYAgOfIogA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And I pretty much immediately figured it out.

Replacing `type fooFn<T> = <T>(t: T) => T;` with `type fooFn<T> = (t: T) => T;` did the trick.

Thanks rubber duck!